# How to I change the icon of an apk file I just created

Tags: android, .net, maui, keytool

I used .NET MAUI to create an android app and then used the keytool program to create a keystore file, then I used the dotnet program to create the apk and aab files. The problem I'm having is the image icon is always that purple square that has .NET printed in it.

Is there any other way to change that icon?

Also, the name of the application i created is called EvenSplit and the files always compile to the name:

com.companyname.evensplit

Is there a way I can have companyname compiled to a specific name?

Thanks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/app-icons?tabs=android

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other way to change that icon?

First, you can change the icon img by changing the `<MauiIcon>`.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Second, if you want to change the icon for each platform, you can check [Use a different icon per platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/app-icons?tabs=android#use-a-different-icon-per-platform).

> Is there a way I can have companyname compiled to a specific name?

Go to the app > manifests > AndroidManifest.xml file and change the android:label field in your application node in AndroidManifest.xml.